# How do I get an access to type information in TypeScript from another (development-time) program?

Tags: reflection, build, typescript

I would like to get a list of function's arguments' types in TypeScript. As it got obvious from a glance on Google search results, TypeScript lacks Java-kind reflection. I've thought there could be some kind of compiler API to get such data for IDE development needs etc., but I've found none.

So how do I get an access to type information in TypeScript from another program (build tool, lint etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've thought there could be some kind of compiler API to get such data for IDE development needs etc., but I've found none.

Its called the "TypeScript Language Service". There are docs for it : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Language-Service-API

Also I have an OSS project that uses it : https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript that has stuff like an AST viewer and a quickfix architecture : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#quickfix

Also have a book with some compiler docs  http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/compiler/overview.html

Comment: So... is it possible to get type from AST node in some straightforward way without playing with positions?

Comment: `Type` requires project wide analysis. You need access to `typeChecker` available on `program` Coincidentally : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664373/how-do-i-determine-the-result-type-of-a-typescript-expression-object

Comment: `node` that you pass in is an AST node, but after binding has happened. If you call `getTypeChecker` it does binding as well ;)

Comment: Aha... thanks! And are the actual type structures describen somewhere? (just need a reference on how to extract types from variable declarations, function params, function return etc.)

Comment: `And are the actual type structures describen somewhere` Not yet. Do let me know if you find relevant docs :) I do use it in our quickfix infrastructure e.g. https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/a91f7e0c935ed2bdc2c642350af50a7a5aed70ad/lib/main/lang/fixmyts/quickFixes/addClassMember.ts#L28-L31

Comment: I see, thank you. And one (hopefully final) question: are things like `const` reassignment, type mismatch etc. automatically checked for me when calling `getTypeChecker` so that I can rely on those assumptions in my tool, or should I call some API or even traverse AST manually and check for them?

Comment: `or should I call some API or even traverse AST manually and check for them` Automatic. Access using the diagnostics API e.g. https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/02365edd952c69518ddbd2e9bfd960073104df6e/lib/main/lang/projectService.ts#L432-L440