# How do I determine the result type of a TypeScript.Expression object?

Tags: typescript, tslint

When working with the TypeScript abstract syntax tree, how do I determine the result type of a TypeScript.Expression object?

I am using TSLint and attempting to find invocations of setTimeout that do not pass an object of type Function as the first parameter. For example, in the following code, I want to know that setTimeout was invoked and that the first parameter is a function.

```
// function that produces a function
var createFunction : () => (() => void) = () => {}; 
// result of createFunction() should be of type function
setTimeout(createFunction());
```

The AST lines up like this:

- setTimeout -> TypeScript.CallExpression
- createFunction() -> TypeScript.Expression

I have tried to use the LanguageService to determine the type of the Expression, but none of the following APIs give me what I need:

- languageServices.getQuickInfoAtPosition
- languageServices.getDefinitionAtPosition
- languageServices.getTypeDefinitionAtPosition

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language service itself doesn't expose that information.

You can use the type checker to do this. Once you have a `program` object from `createProgram`, write:

```
        let typeChecker = program.getTypeChecker();
        let type = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(node);
```