# What is a `Node` in typescript (using TypeChecker)

Tags: typescript

Using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664373/how-do-i-determine-the-result-type-of-a-typescript-expression-object) as a reference. What is a `Node` and how do I get an instance of a `Node` from a `Program`.

The answer to the question above used this example to get the type information at a location *(Which is what I would like to do)*

```
let typeChecker = program.getTypeChecker();
let type = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(node);
```

Now I'm just missing one last piece of the puzzle. What is a `Node` of object do I pass into `getTypeAtLocation` and how would I get an instance of a `Node`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the top-level node for the source file you're interested in processing like so:

```
const root = program.getSourceFile(fileName);
```

Or if you want to process the whole lot:

```
const roots = program.getSourceFiles();
```

Then you can recursively traverse the tree:

```
processNode(root);

function processNode(node: ts.Node) {
   // process this node
   // ....

   // go further down the tree
   ts.forEachChild(node, child => processNode(child));
}
```

With that you should be able to use the likes of `TypeChecker.getSymbolAtLocation()` and `TypeChecker.getTypeAtLocation()` to devise a solution to your other question.

If you don't need to modify the source files you plan to process then it may be easier to write a [custom tslint rule](https://github.com/palantir/tslint#writing-custom-rules).